# Word for "A feeling of lethargy experienced after eating a meal"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

[From this link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20Itis), I found the word to be "the Itis".

Is there a synonym for this word?

> "I got the worst case of ______ after that cheese steak with fries".

Comment: I would suggest staying with "The Itis" when referring to the urban dictionary page. The original word is not something that will be necessary to specify.

Comment: I’ve never heard of *the itis* and without sufficient context would never have guessed what it meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Post-prandial somnolence*, post-prandial sleepiness, or post-prandial fatigue. (The hyphen is optional.)

*Food coma*

See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprandial_somnolence):

> Postprandial somnolence (colloquially known as the itis, food coma, after dinner dip, or postprandial sleep) is a normal state of drowsiness or lassitude following a meal.